# Sequelize Query take all values in where condition

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an `array=[1,2,3]`

Only `1` & `2` are in the database under the column `ID`.

When I perform a query using `WHERE IN`  it gives me result of `1` & `2`.

What I want to do is if all data matches then show me the result otherwise `null`

I am using Sequelize. How can this be done?
Query:

```
 Models.Question.findOne({
                where: {
                    id:1
                },
                include: [{
                        model: Models.QuestionOptions,
                        as: 'options',
                        required: true,
                        where: {
                           id:[1,2,3]
                        }
                }]
            });
```

expect result `Null` because only `1` & `2` are in DB

Comment: Can you please share test data and expected result ?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

`require:true` means `INNER JOIN`. In other words it will only return lines with existing associations(If the condition is also true of course). You should remove it if you want to get all lines(Left Join) even if there is no corresponding association

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using group and having clause.

```
  Models.Question.findOne({
    attributes: ["id"],
    where: {
        id:1
    },
    group: ['id'],
    having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('options.id')), {
      [sequelize.Op.gte]: 3,
    }),
    include: [{
            model: Models.QuestionOptions,
            as: 'options',
            attributes: [],
            required: true,
            where: {
               id:[1,2,3]
            }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Saying Unknown column 'options.id' in 'having clause

Comment: Please check you associations and QuestionOptions contains id column or not